# email validation and email exists check using ko.observable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validation, knockout.js

i want to  apply validations on email if email is valid or not , and after that check in db using ajax to verify email already exist and email already exixt check should work if first check is passed , here is what i did , iam stucked in email_already_exist check that how to validate only if above check is passed , if anyone have idea how to do that

```
// code which checking email is valid
  email: ko.observable((ref = REGISTRY.unsavedUser) != null ? ref.email : void 0).extend({
    required: true,
    email: {
      params: true,
      message: 'Please enter a valid email.'
    },
    focus:true
  }),

  // function to check email exists
  var email_exist_check = function() {
  var errorElement = $('#parent-email-signup');
  var emzil = errorElement.val();

    return = $.ajax({
      url: '/api/v3/email_exists',
      method: 'POST',
      async: false,
      data: {
            email: emzil
          },
      success: function(data){

        console.log(data);

      },
      error: function (response, status) {
         showFlashMessage('An error occured, please try again later.', 'error');
      }
    });
    
    

};
```

email exist function is ready iam stucked that how to use in the above code
please help

Answer (score 1):

Never, never **never** use `async: false` on Ajax calls.

What you need:

An API wrapper, for convenience and code readability later.

```js
const API = {
  email_exists: function (email) {
    return $.post('/api/v3/email_exists', {
      email: email
    }).then(function (result) {
      // evaluate result & return true (email exists) or false (email is free)
      return ...;
    }).fail(function (jqXhr, status, error) {
      showFlashMessage('An error occured, please try again later.', 'error');
      console.log('Error in email_exists', email, jqXhr, status, error);
    });
  },
  // add other API functions in the same way
};
```

and [async validation rule](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Async-Rules) that calls your API:

```js
ko.validation.rules.emailFromAPI = {
  async: true,
  validator: function (val, params, callback) {
    API.email_exists(val).done(function (exists) {
      callback(!exists);    // validation is successful when the email does not exist
    });
  },
  message: 'Please enter a valid email.'
};
```

an observable that uses this rule:

```js
email: ko.observable((ref = REGISTRY.unsavedUser) != null ? ref.email : void 0).extend({
  required: true,
  emailFromAPI: true,
  focus:true
}),
```

Comment: hi sir i need to add different message on two validations (1.email invalid 2. email exists in db.  and if 1st one passed then only 2nd one should execute) how can i do that please help if you have any idea

Comment: @AdarshAwasthi Read the documentation for async validation rules. I've put the link there for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Since ajax is asynchronous you'll have to wait for the server response, returning the ajax call will not wait for the server call to resolve. One way to solve this is using a callback (another would be promises with async/await)

```
var email_exist_check = function(email, onSuccess, onError) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/api/v3/email_exists',
    method: 'POST',
    async: false,
    data: { email },
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
      if (data && !data.error) { return onSuccess(); }
      return onError(data && data.error);
    },
    error: function (response, status) {
       onError(response);
    }
  });
};

// After doing a front-end email verification
email_exist_check(ref.email, () => {
    console.log('Email is valid');
}, (error) => {
    console.error('Something went wrong', error);
});
```